# Windows Recovery API call causes Stack Imbalance

Tags: wpf, pinvoke, unmanaged

I got a strange problem ... I´m trying to implement the Recovery API of Windows Vista+.
Basically it works. But every time I try to call "RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback" I´ll get a StackImbalance exception.

Normally you could ignore it, but if I run the program without a debugger, it crashes because of a buffer overflow on the Stack or something like that...

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public delegate uint ApplicationRecoveryCallback(object pvParameter);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern uint RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]ApplicationRecoveryCallback pRecoveryCallback,
        object pvParameter,
        uint dwPingInterval,
        uint dwFlags);
```

This is my PInvoke implementation.
That´s my call:

```
result = RecoveryAPI.RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback(ApplicationRecovery, null, 5000, 0);
```

It won´t work. I already tried to set the Conventions to CDecl as well as ThisCall. Nothing works ...

Thanks
R

Comment: Try changing your `object` parameters to in ApplicationRecoveryCallback and RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback to `IntPtr`.  I'm making a guess that the marshaller is not marshalling `object` directly to the size of a pointer.

Comment: Same problem ... Still a Stack Imbalance -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17024/Vista-Application-Crash-Recovery-in-C) which showed the right technique. Not only the object´s had to be IntPtr. The delegate as well must be a IntPtr.

You don´t need to set any Conventions. It works with the default.
Just modify the Callback method import like this:

```
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern uint RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback(IntPtr pRecoveryCallback,
        IntPtr pvParameter,
        uint dwPingInterval,
        uint dwFlags);
```

Then call it like this:

```
        RecoveryAPI.ApplicationRecoveryCallback callBack = this.ApplicationRecovery;
        IntPtr methodPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callBack);
        result = RecoveryAPI.RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback(methodPtr, IntPtr.Zero, 5000, 0);
```

It´s quite easy, isn´t it? And it works :)